# How can i add multiple columns to existing dataframe in pyspark aws emr?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I have dataframe like this

`Row(id='123456', name='Computer Science', class='Science')`

and i have like 1000 rows in dataframe.

Now i have function like

```
def parse_id(id):
    id = somestuff
    return new_id
```

for every column i have parse function for that like `parse_name` , `parse_class`

I want to apply those functions to each dataframe row so that it gives new column like `new_id`, 'new_name', 'new_class'

So the resultant dataframe will  be like

`Row(id='123456', name='Computer Science', class='Science', new_id='12345668688', new_name='Computer Science new', new_class='Science new')`

How can i do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest for you to go through the concepts of UDFs in Spark, f.e. this blog post https://changhsinlee.com/pyspark-udf/ has the concept described quite well with enough examples as well.

To your problem, let's assume your input dataframe is in variable `df`, then this code should solve your problem:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
import pyspark.sql.types as t

parse_id_udf = f.udf(parse_id, t.StringType())
parse_name_udf = f.udf(parse_name, t.StringType())
parse_class_udf = f.udf(parse_class, t.StringType())

result_df = df.select(f.col("id"), f.col("name"), f.col("class"),
                      parse_id_udf(f.col("id")).alias("new_id"),
                      parse_name_udf(f.col("name")).alias("new_name"),
                      parse_class_udf(f.col("class")).alias("new_class"))
```